# How to say “I would have to do that” in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, temps-grammatical, constructions

Is this correct?

> Je ne pensais pas que **je serais du avoir à faire cela**.

What I want to say is "I did not think that **I would have to do that**" but I'm having trouble with the **bolded** clauses.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's much too literal. Your English is a bit unclear - did you mean "... that I would have to do that" or "... that I would have had to do that"?

Would have to: *Je ne pensais pas que je devrais faire cela.*

Would have had to: *Je n'avais pas pensé que j'aurais dû faire cela.*

Comment: Alternative version : _Je ne pensais pas que j'aurais à faire cela._

Answer (score 3):

I'm French and it seems to me the best translation would be "Je ne pensais pas que j'aurais à faire ça" ("cela" is rather used for written French).

Comment: Je ne pensais pas: validé par tous. J'aurais à faire ça: même sens mais plus proche de l'anglais que je devrais faire ça.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the best way to say it would be :

> Je ne pensais pas que j'avais à faire ça.

Comment: «j'avais» ou «j'aurais»... hmmmm... the use of "would" tells me it should be «j'aurais», don't you agree ?

Comment: non car : j'avais: I had to. Ce n'est pas ce qui est écrit.

Answer (score 0):

je serais du avoir à faire cela: est **totalement incorrect**. Devoir a pour auxiliaire avoir => j'aurais dû.

réponse:

Je ne pensais pas que j'aurais à faire cela. (futur dans le passé : conditionnel)